# Calling Group SignalR Function from Hub Class

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I had created a Hub Class. All the data gets fetched but when **`Clients.Group(spokeCode).broadCast(message);`** function is called by api it does not execute the broadcast function on my ASP.NET Web Page **(Client Page)**. 
1. I had checked that `/signalR/hubs` is correctly generating. 
2. `OnConnected()` gets successfully called

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public void BroadCastMessage(string spokeCode, String constr)
{
    lock (this)
    {
        string procedureName = "procedureName";

        string message = "message goes here ";

        DataAccessLayer dal = new DataAccessLayer();
        //DataSet ds = dal.Executedataset(constr, procedureName);
        DataSet ds = dal.ExecuteDataset(constr, procedureName, new object[] { spokeCode });


        foreach (var set in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(c => c["SpokeCode"]))
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = set.CopyToDataTable();
                //for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                //{
                foreach (var r in set)
                {
                    message += r.Field<string>("BatchNo") + " Lot No " + r.Field<string>("LotNo");
                    Clients.Group(spokeCode).broadCast(message);
                    //Clients.Group(r.Field<string>("SpokeCode")).BroadCast(message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogging log = new ErrorLogging();
                log.EventLog(ex.Message);
                //Clients.Caller.executeError("An Error has Occured Contact System Administrator");
                Clients.Group(spokeCode).executeError("An Error has been Occured, Contact Administrator");
            }

    }

}
```

Here is the following client code written in JavaScript

```
  connectionHub.client.broadCast = function (message) {
                alert(message);
            };
```

Comment: maybe the client is not in the group? Use fiddler to make sure that the message is being sent from the server in the first place.

Comment: As per Pawel's advice, does the client code get executed if you change it to be broadcast to all clients?

Comment: @adaam When i change the Code from Group to All It get broadcasted to All Users. Here is how i am adding users to the Group http://pastie.org/9941688# Can you please check

Comment: add a breakpoint on JoinToSpokeGroup to confirm the add; does it have the expected spokeCode? how are you setting the query string on the client?

Comment: Well it reaches at the JoinToSpokeGroup and i am using Connection.hub.qs to set up the Query String @LarsHöppner

Comment: please add the SignalR version and how soon you try to send to the group; also, try returning `base.OnConnected()` from OnConnected, then in JoinToSpokeGroup: `await Groups.Add(...)`  and send to the same group right after that; does that arrive? if so, how long does it take?